# Mapping custom MediaType with to JSON MediaType

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jersey, mime-types

I have a requirement to create a REST service(Jersey) which accepts header as "application/com.foo+xml" (+json incase of JSON mime type).

Is there anyway to have 
@Produces("application/com.foo+xml") 
without creating a custom MessageBodyWriter? Is there anyway to map "application/com.foo+xml" to "application/json"?

Just don't want to create a custom class when MediaType "application/com.foo+xml" is same as "application/xml"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you are using JAXB for handling your API messages (request/response) - if not you should look on that. Apparently what you are looking for is possible without creating custom MessageBodyWriter, according to this reference - http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Application-Specific-content-types-and-JAXB-annotations-td6380235.html - "Anything "+json" should work out of the box"... so you would simply need to define your JAXB mappings and it will generate/handle the JSON/XML representations for the `@Consumes` and `@Produces` MediaTypes you have on your API.